# Transpose SQL Table like an Excel Paste Transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose, cross-apply

I have a table:

```
ColName     Value
Desc        Weave
Length      15
Width       12
Height      2
```

I need a functionality like the Paste Transpose option in Excel. This functionality should produce the following output:

```
ColName    Desc    Length    Width    Height
Value      Weave   15        12       2
```

I've seen other postings mention cross apply and pivots, but I've never used this functionality, and I'm not quite able to make anything work this way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: SQL Server has `PIVOT`. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Be aware that whilst you can perform pivots in SQL, you shouldn't expect things to  behave the same as a spreadsheet. In spreadsheets, rows and columns are pretty well the same sort of thing. In an SQL databases, columns and rows are very different types of things (e.g. you cannot have data of different types in the same column in SQL)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL Server

Comment: No CROSS APPLY needed; this is a basic PIVOT. Here's a link to a pretty good walkthrough on PIVOT with examples: https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't get `colname` and `value` into the first column of the report - actually I can't figure out where that would make any sense in a SQL database - Excel maybe, though, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out ..

Having said that - I'd go about it like this ...

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(ColName,Value) AS (
          SELECT 'Desc'   ,'Weave'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Length' ,'15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Width'  ,'12'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Height' ,'2'
)
SELECT * FROM indata
PIVOT (
  MAX(value)
FOR ColName IN ([Desc],[Length],[Width],[Height])
) AS pivtab;

Desc |Length|Width|Height
-----+------+-----+------
Weave|    15|12   |     2
```

Comment: thanks - that works, but not quite how I imagined. Is there any way to pivot without doing an aggregate? I basically need an entire table replicated, not just the MAX input.

Comment: Ahh figured it out - pulled in a unique value field.